# How does spark streaming cache work?

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

Through searching the internet, I learned that by default spark streaming will cache the rdd itself for a batch time, after that, it will be deleted. So we do not need to call rdd.cache() explicitly. Is my understanding correct? Also I have some doubt about the spark cache mechanism, for example:

```
val rdd = some method to generate rdd
rdd.cache()  //will this rdd still be cached in memory?
rdd = rdd.union(another rdd)
```

Any body can explain this question to me please, any help is appreciated!